# How to pass variable to named function with angular $on?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created the following listener:

```
scope.$on('location', updateMap)
```

This worked great, but now updateMap needs to take a variable:

```
function updateMap(request){
...
}
```

I need to pass the variable request:

```
var request = {
    origin: origin, 
    destination: new_destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[attrs.type],
};
```

How do I pass the variable request to the named function?

Comment: Do you mean that each time the `location` event is fired, you need to pass a different `request` parameter ?

Comment: You pass the args with $emit or $broadcast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the job of the broadcast/emit event to send arguments to the listeners, so:

```
scope.$broadcast('location', request);
scope.$emit('location', request);
```

Or if you want to call updateMap with a parameter you just need to call it within the listener function:

```
scope.$on('location', function() {
 updateMap(request);
});
```